# Redis cache want to increment a counter every time data is pulled out of the cache

Tags: java, redis

I have a cache and in this cache I want to store a key which is a URL and a counter. Every time the data is accessed the value will be incremented.

The first problem is that I am using a model

```
CrudRepository<Rate, String>
```

apart from the fact that

```
CrudRepository<Integer, String>
```

Does not work, I need a model because on the model, I can set time to live

```
@RedisHash(value = "Rate", timeToLive = 5)
public class Rate implements Serializable  {
```

But if there is a way to just say a string /integer pair in the cache, with a time to live set. I would be happy to use that.

I know there is an INCR function on keys but the docs say
The INCR command is used to increment the string representing a integer value stored at the specified key by one. If the key does not exist, it is first created and set to 0 before performing the increment operation. If the key exist but value stored at the key is of wrong datatype ( not string datatype ) or contains a string value that can not be represented as a integer then error is returned. This operation is limited to 64 bit signed integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went a different direction using StringRedisTemplate instead of CrudRepository

```
public boolean isAllowed(String url, String maxRate) {
        logger.info("URL is "+url);
        boolean allow = false;
        ValueOperations<String, String> valueOps = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
        String rate = valueOps.get(url);
        logger.info("RATE "+rate);
        if(rate == null) {
            valueOps.set(url, maxRate, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            allow = true;
        } else {
            valueOps.decrement(url, 1);
            if(Integer.parseInt(rate) > 0) {
                allow = true;
            }
        }
        return allow;
    }
```